# Need to not overwrite a file with Wise Installer

Tags: wise

I create the installer for my application with Wise Installation Express 7.0. In my installation there is a file that holds user names and passwords. It needs to be installed/uninstalled when the application is installed or uninstalled. When the application is upgraded, though, that file needs to NOT be overwritten. How can I do that with Wise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you solved this in a timely manner, but for others' sake:

In the **Setup Editor** tab, define a **Component** that represents your file, specifying its directory and its file name in the **KeyPath**.

Right-click to specify **Details**, and check the **Leave Installed on Uninstall** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. When I build my next release, I'll try this.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and the password file is now left behind when my application is uninstalled. That should suit my needs just fine. Thanks.